# The USB key is not recognizable in 'Use a device'

Tags: windows, usb, kali-linux, dual-boot

I want to boot my computer with Kali Linux on my laptop (ThinkPad X1 Carbon). I followed the following [procedure](https://techlog360.com/how-to-dual-boot-kali-linux-v2-0-with-windows-10/) in disabling secure boot and fast boot. How could we ensure that my computer is set to boot from CD / USB in my BIOS?

[image]

I think my real problem is when I went to `Settings` -> `Update and Security` -> `Recovery` -> `Restart now`, I am supposed to find my USB key in the previous picture, but it is not the case. Could anyone be able to help me to reveal this USB key in this menu?

Comment: Try this [guide](http://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/access-bios-and-change-boot-order-windows/) and see if it helps.

Comment: You say you want CD/USB, so I suggest you choose "USB CD" on the screen you show. Background - there are a number of devices that the system can boot from, in addition to the floppy disk, hard drive and cdrom shown there is zip drive. You are selecting which to emulate with this menu.

Comment: @icarus or usb Hdd, if your usb is a usb mass storage device (not a CD drive connected via usb). [I love the icons, so you can quickly see which option is which.]

Comment: @richard it is not a matter of it being a mass storage device, all `USB keys` are mass storage devices. An `iso` image has a very different information at the start than a hard disk image although you can have `hybrid` images. The OP needs to select the boot method to match the format of the data on the boot media,

Comment: @icarus, yes that is also correct.